# Sql querying a new column as array from a set of results from another table

Tags: sql, arrays, json, postgresql, join

i'm trying to make a join query of two tables and include a new column that is actually a result from a query from another table, but the new column is an array, can be a json perhaps. To demonstrate I have this table :

[image]

and each **entry** can have several **plots** :

[image]

I know I can select all plots using the entry id, but that's not what I want. I want to **select all entries**, and **have all its plots in array form**, so that I can have them in a nice single table :

[image]

I don't know really where to look. So how do I return an array as a column of a join query. Thanks! I'm using PostgreSQL if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `array_agg()`:

```
select e.id, e.entry_name, array_agg(plot_name)
from entry e join
     plot p
     on e.id = p.entry_id
group by e.id, e.entry_name;
```

Comment: This is great! Hi, If you don't mind. a follow up question. If the array_agg are an array of id's and say array_agg(plot_id). And I wish to query further from another table say "seed" table with fields id and seed_name related by the plot_id (one to one relp only, one plot= one seed) and wishes to have the array of seed_name's instead of plot_name. What modification do I apply? Thanks!